# How to detect LI element number inside an UL elemen using its class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have an UL element with its child LI elements for example I need to know what is the position or number (i.e. 4 in list given below) of first LI element containing class "Branding" in LI items. I need its solution in jQuery.

```
<ul class="thumbs">
   <li class="logos">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="logos">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="logos">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="Branding">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="Branding">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="Branding">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="Branding">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="website">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="website">Some Inner contents</li>
   <li class="website">Some Inner contents</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To count:

```
var ul = $('ul.thumbs');

ul.children('.logos').size(); //3
ul.children('.Branding').size(); //4
ul.children('.website').size(); //3
```

To get the index:

```
ul.children('.logos').first().index(); //0
ul.children('.Branding').first().index(); //3
ul.children('.website').first().index(); //7
```

Comment: ul.children('.branding').first().index(); // 3 - I upvoted Andre for using .first() !

Comment: Simplest solution. Imran, go with this.

Comment: Thanks JP and Johannes, Yes it is simpler and quick thanks Andre

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to know the position, I think you need to loop:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
var retIndex = 0;
$.each(".ul li", function(index, value) { 
    retIndex = index;
    if(this.hasClass("branding"))
    {
        alert('found at: ' + index);
        return retIndex;
    }
});
```